# Como produzir JSON no formato que o Highcharts espera?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, highcharts

Tenho o seguinte código em C#:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dataResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataResult["data"] = new List<object[]>();
dataResult["name"] = i;
foreach (var item in query)
{
    object[] values = new object[2];
    values[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ini) ;
    values[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ir);
    ((List<object[]>)dataResult["data"]).Add(values);
}
```

Com ele gero o seguinte JSON:

```
  var data = [
         {"TESTE2008",23.4,2},
         {"TESTE2008",24.4,3},
         {"TESTE2008",25.4,4},
         {"TESTE2008",26.4,5},
         {"TESTE2008",27.4,6},
         {"TESTE2008",28.4,7},
         {"TESTE2008",29.4,8},
         {"TESTE2008",30.4,9},
         {"TESTE2009",30.4,2},
         {"TESTE2009",31.4,3},
         {"TESTE2009",32.4,4},
         {"TESTE2009",33.4,5},
         {"TESTE2009",34.4,6},
         {"TESTE2009",35.4,7},
         {"TESTE2009",36.4,8},
         {"TESTE2009",37.4,9},
];
```

e gostaria que os dados estivessem formatados da seguinte forma:

```
series: [{
                name: 'TESTE2008',
                data: [[23.4,2],[24.4,3],[25.4,4],[26.4,5],[27.4,6],[28.4,7],[29.4,8],[30.4,9]
]},
            {
                name: 'TESTE2009',
                data: [[30.4,2],[31.4,3],[32.4,4],[33.4,5],[34.4,6],[35.4,7],[36.4,8],[37.4,9]]},

        });
```

Como alterar meu código para produzir a saída desejada?

Comment: Na verdade tem dois erros aí. 1. Seu [tag:jSon] está sendo gerado errado. Esse [tag:jSon] que está na pergunta não é um [tag:jSon] válido. Todo objeto no [tag:jSon] precisa ser nomeado. 2. O [tag:highcharts] não aceita um `array` como um valor se um dado.

Comment: Se você precisar se dois valores em uma única serie, na verdade você precisa de duas series diferentes.

Comment: Consegui montar uma série, mas não estou conseguindo montar mais de uma. Poderia verificar o que esta de errado com o script que coloquei nesta duvida:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/varias-series-em-highchart-mvc-asp-net

Comment: Seu jSon precisa ser assim `[{
 name: 'TESTE2008',
 data: [23.4,2,24.4,3,25.4,4,26.4,5,27.4,6,28.4,7,29.4,8,30.4,9]
}, {
 name: 'TESTE2009',
 data: [30.4,2,31.4,3,32.4,4,33.4,5,34.4,6,35.4,7,36.4,8,37.4,9]
}]`

Comment: Consegui, Obrigado pela ajuda...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Experimente algo nesse sentido, não sou bom em [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) mas acho que vai gerar da forma que você precisa

```
    /*
        [{ name: 'Huguinho', data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2] },
        { name: 'Zezinho', data: [24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5] },
        { name: 'Luizinho', data: [17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0] }]
    */

    var objVet = new object[] { new { name = "Huguinho", data = new object[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2 } },
                                new { name = "Zezinho", data = new object[] { 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5 } },
                                new { name = "Luizinho", data = new object[] { 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0 } }};

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJson = js.Serialize(objVet);
    return strJson;
```

Comment: Mudei a forma da pegunta para poder expressar melhor a minha duvida.