# Como produzir JSON no formato que o Flot espera?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, flot

Dúvida sobre como serializar para retornar esse JSON.

Estou usando a biblioteca Flot (http://www.flotcharts.org/) para apresentar um gráfico. Sei gerar os gráficos.

Em minha view estou usando assim :

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/graficos/GeraTesteFlot',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (retorno) {
                $.plot($("#divFlot"), [retorno], options);                
            }
        });
```

Mas estou com dificuldade gerar o JSON no formato correto.
Preciso de um JSON assim :

```
  [
      { label: "José", data: [[1, 2], [2, 5]] }, 
      { label: "Maria", data: [[1, 5], [2, 3]] }
  ]
```

E tento gerá-lo com o código abaixo :

```
    public JsonResult GeraTesteFlot()
    {
        // Exemplo de retorno desejado : 
        // É um array de series, e cada série tem uma label e um array de "data"
        //
        // Ex:
        //  [
        //      { label: "José", data: [[1, 2], [2, 5]] }, 
        //      { label: "Maria", data: [[1, 5], [2, 3]] }
        //  ];

        List<object> series = new List<object>();
        series.Add(new
        {
            label = "José",
            data = new[] { new double[] { 1, 2}, new double[] { 2, 5} }
        });

        series.Add(new
        {
            label = "Maria",
            data = new[] { new double[] { 1, 5}, new double[] { 2, 3} }
        });

        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Porém esse código me retorna o JSON assim :

```
  [
      { "label": "José", "data": [[1, 2], [2, 5]] }, 
      { "label": "Maria", "data": [[1, 5], [2, 3]] }
  ]
```

O problema são as `""` aspas duplas no nome dos atributos. Ao invés de `"label": "José"`, preciso de `label: "José"` sem as `""` no `label`.

Como fazer?

Comment: Tem certeza que o problema é as `""`? O formato `{"chave": valor}` é o formato correto para JSON. Esta dando algum erro no console?

Comment: @Wakim se eu pego a string retornada e tiro as aspas do nome do objeto, aí vai.

Comment: Tentei con JavaScriptSerializer() conforme essa resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5971/155 de uma questão similar, porém era sobre HighCharts, mas não rolou. A string gerada também continha aspas duplas no nome dos objetos.

Comment: Em outro gráfico, no caso um gráfico de pizza, usei algo parecido porém apartir de uma query LINQ e foi gerado no formato que quero.

Comment: @Wakim você estava certo. Só percebi o erro quando repassei a pergunta para PT.SO! Meu erro estava no retorno na função Ajax que estava `$.plot($("#divFlot"), [retorno], options);`, na pergunta eu tinha colocado o formato correto, que é `$.plot($("#divFlot"), retorno, options);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Wakim comentou, o formato gerado já estava correto. O que eu tinha errado era na chamada Ajax.

A chamada correto deve ser

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/graficos/GeraTesteFlot',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (retorno) {
                $.plot($("#divFlot"), retorno, options);                
            }
        });
```

Ou seja, onde estava `$.plot($("#divFlot"), [retorno], options);` o correto é              `$.plot($("#divFlot"), retorno, options);`

Após essa correção, o gráfico gerou normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Ao definir seu `data`, certifique-se de passar o retorno do `Controller` dentro do método JavaScript `JSON.parse()`:

```
...
data: JSON.parse(retorno),
...
```